# MongoDB: How to get documents older than 30 days?

Tags: mongodb

I know this question has been asked before, but it's not working for me. I am very sorry for asking this again.

I have a table in which each document has a `addedon` field:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
...
"addedon" : "Nov 21, 2018 8:09:35 AM", 
...
}
```

I want to get all documents which are older than 30 days:

```
db.mycollection.find({"addedon":{$lt: new Date(Date.now() - 30*24*60*60 * 1000)}})
```

But the results come out as empty. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you ONLY want to use your field "addedon", or you are flexible in using _id instead of "addedon" to do that?

Comment: What's the type of the "addedon" field? A String or a Date/ISODate?

Comment: @rodrigoap "addedon" is a string, which should be why I am not able to get expected results.

Comment: Right, and to make things worst the date format you have wont work with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to revert to javascript when the *addedon* field is a string:

```
db.dateasstring.find({ $where: function() {
    return (new Date(this.addedon) < new Date(Date.now() - 30*24*60*60 * 1000));
}})
```

Comment: how can i find dates older than 30 days?